# Wordpress using php session variables in templates with cache

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am using a php session variable to store and show some data between couple of  wordpress page templates. It is working perfectly in my development server but the session variable is not getting set in the live wpengine hosting. I think they have some wordpress caching plugin enabled.

I am using the following code in the functions.php to enable session. Anyone have any idea to workaround this issue ?

```
function register_session() {
        if ( ! session_id() ) {
            session_start();
        }
    }
add_action( 'init', 'register_session' );
```

Comment: have you tested calling out the session name in the beginning of each template file. 
session_name("your_session_name");

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [WordPress Native PHP Sessions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/)

WordPress core does not use PHP sessions, but with this plugin, you can have this feature.